# Как увеличить скорость работы сайта Front?

Tags: php, javascript, css, laravel, оптимизация-сайтов

На сайте backend отрабатывает за 50 мс, а фронт забирает кучу времени. В итоге полсекунды на отображение страницы с использованием кэша, без кэша 700 мс. Есть правила и способы увеличить скорость отображения?

Для бека используется `Laravel`.

Comment: А зачем оптимизировать то что не нуждается в этом? Ну получите вы выгоду в 100-150 миллисекунд, врядли пользователь это заметит. Имеет ли это смысл делать по правилу Парето?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Если запустить сейчас то сложно будет разгрестись потом

Comment: 700 мс — это время отрисовки или время ответа?

Comment: 700 это время ответа от сервера + время отрисовки

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Оптимизация js одна из острых тем. Что Вы можете сделать:

1) Вы можете использовать встроенный профилировщик хрома http://prntscr.com/ejumdm и проанализировать какой скрипт/метод у Вас больше всего загружается и оптимизировать.

1.1) Есть например гугловский механизм [PageSpead](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=ru)

2) Минимизация скриптов. По хорошему Вы можете минимизировать скрипты и стили с помощью инструментов для сборки [grunt](https://gruntjs.com/), [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) .

3) Если даже минимизация не помогает. Можно использовать [AMD](https://learn.javascript.ru/modules) для асинхронной загрузки модулей. Для этого можно использовать, например, [webpack](http://webpack.github.io/docs/)

Comment: я бы [**sitespeed.io**](https://www.sitespeed.io/) вместе с или вместо Google PageSpeed упомянул. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных да, точно. Я кстати его забыл упомянуть. Очень классная штука.

Comment: sitespeed.io - это набор инструментов для проверки производительности. И одни из них  [webpagetest](https://www.webpagetest.org/) очень удобная штука. Вот, например, по этому [скрину](http://prntscr.com/el53q2)  уже можно сделать вывод, что картинки требую компрессии. И что в  [стили](http://prntscr.com/el54v4) тоже долго грузятся (как оказалось там картинка в base64).

Answer (score 11):

Я бы посоветовал вам оптимизировать весь статический контент на сайте.

#### Сжатие графики

В вашем случае кроме сжатия стилей и скриптов посоветую сжимать и графику. К примеру, картинки можно легко сжать без потери качества только за счет удаление exif-данных. На реальном сайте можно сократить размер картинок в среднем на 70%, что на современном сайте в среднем равняется примерно 4 МБ. Пример на `gulp`:

```
var
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    imageminJR = require('imagemin-jpeg-recompress'),
    imageminSvgo = require('imagemin-svgo');

// Optimizing images
gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
    gulp.src('./img/**/*')
        .pipe(imagemin([
            imageminJR({
                method: 'ms-ssim'
            }),
            imageminSvgo({
                plugins: [
                    {removeViewBox: false}
                ]
            })
        ]))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/img/'))
});
```

А для браузеров, которые понимают легковесный формат `webp` (формат разработан Google), можно сделать еще такой вариант изображений:

```
var
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    webp = require('gulp-webp');

// Generate Webp
gulp.task('webp', function() {
    gulp.src('./img/**/*')
        .pipe(webp())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/img/'))
});
```

#### Оптимизация скриптов

Сперва объедините все скрипты в один файл и минифицируйте их. Это помет сократить количество HTTP-запросов и размер файлов:

```
var
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

// Concat JS
gulp.task('js', function(){
    gulp.src([
        './js/jquery.js',
        './js/wow.js',
        './js/menu.js',
        './js/scrollspy.js',
        './js/main.js',
        './js/temp/contact.bundled.js',
        './js/owl.carousel.js'
    ])
        .pipe(concat('script.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/'))
});
```

#### Оптимизация стилей

Кроме обычной минификации стилей можно использовать и продвинутую - объединять дубликаты классов и @media. Пример на `gulp` из моего [web-starter-kit](https://github.com/1000tech/web-starter-kit):

```
var
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    stylus = require('gulp-stylus'),

    // Минифицирует CSS, объединяет классы. Не ломает CSS, в отличие от cssnano, который, к примеру, может неправильно выставлять z-index
    csso = require('gulp-csso'),

    // Объединяет все @media
    cmq = require('gulp-combine-mq'),

    // Сокращает CSS-селекторы    
    gs = require('gulp-selectors'),

    // Проставляет вендорные префиксы
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),

    livereload = require('gulp-livereload'),
    nib = require('nib');

// Compiling Stylus in CSS
gulp.task('css', function() {
    gulp.src('./styl/*.styl')
        .pipe(stylus({
            use: nib()
        }))
        .pipe(cmq())
        .pipe(csso())
        .pipe(autoprefixer('last 3 versions'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css/'))
});
```

А если совсем делать нечего, то можно еще и селекторы сократить:

```
// Minify selectors
    gulp.task('gs', function() {
        var ignores = {
            classes: ['active', 'menu', 'nav', 'slide', 'error', 'form-control', 'loader', 'showLoader', 'fadeLoader', 'webp', 'wow', 'owl-*', 'i-*'],
            ids: '*'
        };
        gulp.src(['./public/**/*.css', './public/**/*.html'])
            .pipe(gs.run({}, ignores))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'))
    });
```

Кстати, наверняка у вас есть классы, добавляющиеся через JS, поэтому предварительно стоит все такие классы вынести в переменную `ignores`.

#### Кеширование статики на стороне пользователя

Также бы посоветовал кешировать скрипты и стили на стороне пользователя, чтобы исключить их повторную загрузку, если они не изменились:

```
<FilesMatch ".(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|svg|swf|js|css|pdf|woff2|woff|ttf|eot)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>
```

И включить gzip сжатие на сервере:

```
# сжатие text, html, javascript, css, xml:
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 7):

Детали конкретно вашего случая вам надо смотреть в DevTools / Timeline и пользоваться каждым из методов с оглядкой туда, потому что общие советы по оптимизации в конкретном случае могут только навредить. К советам выше могу добавить следующие:

- Посмотреть в таймлайне детали вашего *critical rendering path*. Постараться его максимально сократить:

  1. Убрать с него блокирующий CSS. Выделить, например, при помощи **[critical](https://www.npmjs.com/package/critical)** стили для первого экрана и поместить их инлайном в `<head>` → `<style>`. Остальной CSS загружать асинхронно при помощи **[loadCSS](https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS)**.
  2. Скрипты загружать с атрибутом `defer` / `async`.
- Активно использовать `<link rel="preload">` — в современных браузерах прирост в скорости весьма значительный, но использовать его надо с умом и таймлайном.
- Изображения готовить в нескольких размерах и использовать тег `<picture>`; отдавать изображения в формате WebP браузерам, которые его могут читать при помощи этого же тега.

  1. Не инлайнить изображения, пропущенные через base64-декодер (в CSS тоже).
  2. Если изображений много, то загружать их «лениво», например, при помощи **[lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes)** (хорошо дружит с `<picture>`).
  3. Если есть тяжелые PNG, в которых используется прозрачность, посмотреть в сторону конвертирования такого PNG в JPG + SVG.
- Если используются кастомные шрифты, то их также рекомендую загружать асинхронно, например, при помощи **[fontfaceobserver](https://fontfaceobserver.com/)**.

Источники:

> Статья об оптимизации вообще: https://dev.to/sanjsanj/optimising-the-front-end-for-thebrowser
>
> О `<link rel="preload">` https://medium.com/reloading/a-link-rel-preload-analysis-from-the-chrome-data-saver-team-5edf54b08715
>
> WebP https://css-tricks.com/using-webp-images/
>
> Base64 https://csswizardry.com/2017/02/base64-encoding-and-performance/, https://csswizardry.com/2017/02/base64-encoding-and-performance-part-2/
>
> PNG → JPG + SVG (Transparent JPG) https://css-tricks.com/transparent-jpg-svg/

Answer (score 5):

Для начала прогоните несколько ключевых страниц через Google PageSpeed Insights.
Google вам выдаст примерно такие проблемы и рекомендации:

1. Настройте кеширование статичных ресурсов (css, js, изображения). Это можно сделать с помощь настроек nginx. А если у вас виртуальный хостинг - обратитесь в техподдержку. Обычно они делают это бесплатно.
2. Сожмите все изображения на сайте. Автоматизировать этот процесс помогает https://optipic.io/ru/ - просто подключается к любому сайту на php без какой-либо "танцев с бубном". Скачиваете скрипт на свой сайт, а сервис сам найдет все картинки и сожмет их.
3. Объедините все css в один css-файл, все js в один js-файл.
4. Перенесите максимально все css и js в нижнюю часть html-кода.
5. Избавьтесь от всех ресурсов, которые отдают 404 ошибку (или поправьте ссылки на них).

Плюс к этому прогоните ключевые страницы сайта через https://tools.pingdom.com/. Этот сервис даст понимание, какие именно ресурсы замедляют загрузку страниц. К примеру, часто оказывается что какие-то сторонние виджеты тормозят сайт или большие (тяжелые) ресурсы (видео, большой js и т.п.). Со сторонними виджетами можно попробовать использовать async или пообщаться с их техподдержкой (они должны быть заинтересованы, чтобы их виджеты грузились максимально быстро). Если ни то, ни то не помогает, то посмотрите альтернативные сторонние сервисы, которые грузятся более быстро.

Answer (score 3):

Нужно сжимать картинки, скрипты, все ресурсы, объединять и кешировать.

.htaccess для ленивых (gzip, кеширование):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    #GZIP
    AddEncoding gzip .gz
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.gz -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.gz [QSA,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    #GZIP
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>

ServerSignature Off

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
    #кэшировать html и htm файлы на один день
    <FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=43200"
    </FilesMatch>
    #кэшировать css, javascript и текстовые файлы на одну неделю
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|txt)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
    </FilesMatch>
    #кэшировать флэш и изображения на месяц
    <FilesMatch "\.(flv|swf|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
    </FilesMatch>
    #отключить кэширование
    <FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, max-age=0"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    #по умолчанию кеш в 5 секунд
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
    #кэшировать флэш и изображения на месяц
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    #кэшировать css, javascript и текстовые файлы на одну неделю
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
    #кэшировать html и htm файлы на один день
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 43200 seconds"
    #кэшировать xml файлы на десять минут
    #ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>
```

Comment: спасибо, у меня настроен gzip через nginx

Answer (score 3):

Почему никто не зашел глубже?) Сделать Apache бэкендом и Nginx обратным прокси для фронтенда, тем самым иметь высокую скорость!