# Оптимизация скорости загрузки сайта

Tags: html, jquery, css, вёрстка, оптимизация-сайтов

Ребят, знаю что здесь вопросы подобного рода не приветствуются, но все же вынужден попросить вас о помощи. Есть [сайт](https://theappsdepot.com/). Есть страница приложения ([такого типа страница](https://theappsdepot.com/games/strategy/clash-of-clans)) и грузится она достаточно долго. По данным разных сервисов от 3,5 до 13 секунд.

Все js- и css-файлы минимизируются и компилятся в один. По изображениям - буду использовать lazy-load. Есть ли какие-либо еще предложения по оптимизации скорости загрузки?

Comment: https://gtmetrix.com , https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=ru - отличные ресурсы, которые укажут тебе что грузит стр. и как оптимизировать

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как увеличить скорость работы сайта Front?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/639423/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-front)

Answer (score 2):

1. Разместите шрифты локально, у себя на сервере.
2. Картинки у вас 110х110, а на сервере лежат 120х120.
3. Используйте прогрессивный jpg.
4. Размеры изображений не указаны ни в css, ни в html
5. Используйте методику Critical Path css.
6. Разделите js на два файла, тот который нужен для отображения страницы и тот, который можно загрузить позднее.
7. Используйте inline svg вместо отдельных файлов.

Основное время вы тратите на загрузку миллиона картинок. При этом в верхней 1000px картинок не так много. В общем нужно в начале бросить все силы на то, что бы показать сайт посетителю как можно быстрее, системными шрифтами, убого, топорно, но показать. А потом в фоне подгружать все плюшки.

Простите если ничего нового не сказал...

Comment: 1. Внешнее подключение шрифтов обусловлено двумя причинами. Во-первых, `Roboto` и `Roboto Slab` весьма распространены и вероятность того что они подгрузятся кэшем очень большая. А во-вторых, подключая их локально, я не знаю почему, но они "плывут". Вот просто тупо блюрятся и все тут..

Comment: 2. По изображениям - тут я буду использовать lazy-load, т.е. картинки будут подгружаться при доскролле, а не сразу после загрузки страницы.

Comment: 7. Можно подробней про `inline svg`? Буду оч благодарен за ссылку

Comment: 1. А как вы подключаете? Нужно воспользоваться одним из сервисов рендера веб-шрифтов, типа  fontsquirrel. Если вы подключите их локально, то они ТОЧНО закешируются. К тому же вы в курсе что гугла вы грузите не только ext наборы, но и греческие, вьетнамские шрифты?

Comment: 7. Ну а куда подробнее то? В html вставляете через тег `svg`, в css через base64. Все для того чтобы избавится от загрузки лишнего файла.

Comment: Вот `fontsquirrel` и использую.. результат откровенно паршивый. К тому же подгружаемые через google fonts файлы весят 1 с копейками и 0,5 кб, время на их загрузку мизерное, словом, в моей ситуации локальное подключение не оправдано, я считаю. За совет в любом случае спасибо)